# How can I connect my 30 amp electric dryer to a 50 amp plug?

Tags: electrical, dryer, receptacle

I bought a used electric dryer and the connection that came with it says it's 30amp.  I also have an old school plug in my wall that doesn't go with the connection provided.  My current plug has 3 equal lengths that  are like this

```
 |
\ /
```

But the one that comes with it is almost the same but has an L shape on the top plug that looks something like this

```
 L
\ /
```

So I assumed that I had to find a new connection that looked like this

```
 |
\ /
```

with 30 amps. 
Which I had no luck with.

So the man at home depot gives me a 50 amp connection that is also an 8 gauge.  It seems like the one that came with a dryer is a 10 gauge, not sure if it makes a difference.  So I came home and thought I'd take a look at the breaker.  The breaker is 30amps for the dryer, the plug on the wall says 50amps and the dryer says 120/280V- 23A and it also says 120/240V-26A.  So what do I do next? How can I fix this problem? Mind you, I have never dealt with anything like this before and I am also a woman lol. I recently purchased a brand spanking new Samsung gas dryer but the new apartment complex we moved into doesn't have a gas line so I am stuck using an electric dryer that I bought at a yard sale today for $50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an incorrect receptacle installed at your apartment. Some genius just replaced the existing 30A dryer receptacle with the incorrect 50A range receptacle for some reason rather than doing it right.

You only real option is to get the landlord/super/etc to have the receptacle replaced with the proper 30A dryer receptacle. The cord you have on the dryer is correct, albeit the old style 3-prong version.

Comment: Great! Thank's! I went to Lowes and they told me the same thing.  So that, I shall do.  I went to the laundromat last night and it was quite a fun experience.  I met a lot of new people :)  All I need now is to get the landlord to fix it and since my stove hasn't been working properly since I moved in and she hasn't fixed that yet, then I am guessing the dryer situation will also take some time.  Thanks for the feedback and I will definitely take your advice. :)

Answer (score 1):

As a renter, you need to know that verbal agreements are not binding in matters of real estate.  In other words, inform your landlord in WRITING that the receptacle is not up to code.  Make sure to communicate in writing.